# Should I water before or after a tomato feed?

Tags: watering, tomatoes, fertilizer

I'm just back from a few days away and my tomatoes need to be watered (they were watered almost daily by friends while I was away, but it hasn't rained in awhile so they need watering).  I also want to give them a tomato feed as they are still producing new fruit.

Does it matter if I water before or after I put the tomato feed? Will watering after feeding dilute the feed?

Comment: Can you add more details?  Were you not watering when your were away and how many days was that?  Why do you say it needs to be fertilized?  Pictures of the plants would be helpful as well

Comment: Please see my edits @JStorage. The plants were being watered by friends, so they aren't that dry, it's just that it's pretty warm and hasn't rained so they need daily watering.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it does not matter whether you water before or after.  I like to first fertilize and mix the fertilizer with the existing soil and then water.  I think it is much easier to work with soil before watering and hence my preference.